# Not able to update one of the key value by using JSON_MODIFY function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following json record and I'm trying to update the 'counter2' value to 2000 using JSON_MODIFY function. The query doesn't throw any exception but at the same time the value is not getting updated.

Table Data:

[image]

Json data:

```
[ {"counter1": 9,
"counter2": 1000,
"counter3": 109 }]
```

SQL:

```
UPDATE test01
set json_data = JSON_MODIFY(json_data,'$.counter2',2000)
where test01_id =10
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you remove the square brackets it works.  Are you sure that the square brackets are what you want?  The brackets make this an array--doesn't look like it's supposed to be an array.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688321/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-square-brackets-in-json

Comment: Thank you @TonyHinkle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 'counter' properties are in an object within an array, so your JSON path in JSON_MODIFY isn't correct. You need to reference the index of the item in the array to correctly update the value:

```
UPDATE test01
set json_data = JSON_MODIFY(json_data,'$[0].counter2',2000)
where test01_id =10
```

If you had additional objects in the array with different counter 1/2/3 values, then you would need to reference them with their correct index, i.e. [1], [2] and so on. You can see a working example of this [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7cff53e48ca5fd93e29f0660b3d6e168).

Comment: That works, thank you.